# what technology I can use for real time chat application between android and windows desktop application?

Tags: android, windows, chat, real-time

I want to create one chat application for android and windows. So how can I do?
which technology I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You had better use an WCF (Web Service),with you do this, you can even put Apple, windows IPhoneand any other plataform.

WCF put a service online that can be consumed by other appliccation clients.

Comment: but for real time chat what can I use?

Comment: Yes! It is not so hard